# Is it possible to add Google form file uploader through app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

It's possible now to add manually file uploader to Google form, my main question is it possible to add this through google script instead of doing it manually?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that as of now.

However, there is already a Feature Request reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72151985).

You can subscribe to this by clicking on the star ☆ next to the Issue number in order to receive updates and to give more priority to the bug.

Comment: Thanks for it! However, issue was opened in 01/2018 and we are in 11/2019 and still nothing so I do not except anything...

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by `so I do not except anything`